# How can I remove all unneeded whitespaces in string but keep symbols like '\n'?

Tags: python, regex

I have such a string:

```py
s = 'Hello   \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'
```

And I need to get this:

```py
'Hello \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'
```

I tried to use `split` and `join` like:

```py
' '.join('Hello   \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'.split())
```

But I'm getting this:

```py
'Hello World!Today is a wonderful day'
```

Regular expressions like:

```py
re.sub(r"\s+", " ", 'Hello   \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day')
```

are giving the same result.

Comment: If I remember correctly I don’t think you see new lines when evaluating an expression at the Python interpreter like that. I think you need to print the string with print to see the new lines as line breaks.

Comment: What exactly is the rule for which spaces to keep?

Comment: You would need to construct your own bracket expression that's equivalent to `\s`, but minus the `\n`. There's no way to say "`\s` except `\n`", but if are using the `ASCII` flag, you can easily define the equivalent bracket expression `[ \t\r\f\v]`. (Update: clearly, I overlooked `\S`.)

Comment: I think `\v` also matches newline characters, so you should not have that in your bracket expression.

Comment: Can you explain what a whitespace is to you ? Is it this `[^\S\r\n]` or is it this `\s` ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need to shrink all extra spaces into one whitespace

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly they are always appear before \n
Unneeded whitespaces for me are all extra spaces that should be shrinked into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you could do.

You could simply only replace any occurrence of at least one space with a single space:

```
re.sub(r'( )+', ' ', s)
```

To cover more types of (horizontal) whitespace, you could include tabs (`\t`) and feed (`\f`) characters (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xwdeTv/1)):

```
re.sub(r'[\t\f ]+', ' ', s)
```

Alternatively, instead of specifying the characters you *do* want to replace, you could *exclude* the ones you *don't* want to replace (double negative!):

```
re.sub(r'[^\S\n\r]+', ' ', s)
```

In this last example, the `^` signifies that any character *not* present in the list should be matched, the `\S` signifies all *non*-whitespace characters, and `\n` and `\r` are newline and carriage return characters. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RRZssi/1).

Answer (score 2):

Using `str`'s methods you might get desired output following way

```
s1= 'Hello   \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'
' '.join(i for i in 'Hello   \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'.split(' ') if i)
```

gives

```
'Hello \nWorld!\nToday is a wonderful day'
```

Explanation: split at space characters then use comprehension to filter out empty string (those does arise from adjacent spaces) then join what was left

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do that for each of two interpretations of the question.

**First interpretation: where there are two or more of the same whitespace character in a row, other than newlines (`\n`), remove all but one of those characters.**

Replace each match of the regular expression

```
([ \t\r\f\v])\1*(?=\1)
```

with an empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lsFhcg/1)

This regular expression has the following elements.

```
(               Begin capture group 1
  [ \t\r\f\v]   Match a whitespace other than a newline (`\n`)
)               End capture group 1
\1*             Match the character in character class 1 zero or more times 
(?=\1)          Positive lookahead asserts that the next character matches
                the content of character class 1
```

---

Alternatively, replace each match of

```
([ \t\r\f\v])\1+
```

with the contents of capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETBLvl/1)

This regular expression has the following elements.

```
(              Begin capture group 1
  [ \t\r\f\v]  Match a whitespace character other than \n
)              End capture group 1
\1+            Match the content of capture group 1 one or more times
```

**Second interpretation: where there are two or more of whitespace character in a row, other than newlines (`\s`), remove all but the last whitespace character.**

Replace each match of the regular expression

```
[ \t\r\f\v](?=[ \t\r\f\v])
```

with an empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmVddp/1)

This regular expression has the following elements.

```
[ \t\r\f\v]+    Match one or more whitespace characters other than `\n`
(?=             Begin a positive lookahead
  [ \t\r\f\v]   Match a whitespace character other than `\n`
)               End positive lookahead
```

---

Alternatively, replace each match of

```
[ \t\r\f\v]{2,}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YubqXC/1)

This regular expression reads, "match a whitespace character other than a newline (`\n`) two or more times, as many as possible.